# My array counter is 1 step behind. How do I resolve this?

Tags: reactjs

User clicks a number 1-10 and then that populates an array which is then displayed as a list item. The problem is that the array always starts at 0 which is what the state is originally set to and then the array is one step behind on display the number previously pushed.

[image]

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Scoreboard from './Components/Scoreboard'
import Pins from './Components/Pins'
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [pinCount, setPinCount] = useState(0);
  const [scoresArr, setScoresArr] = useState([]);

  const addScore = (pins) => {
    setPinCount(pins)
    console.log(pinCount)
    scoresArr.push(pinCount)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      pinCount = {pinCount}
      <Pins addScore={addScore}/>
      <Scoreboard scoresArr={scoresArr}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Scoreboard.js

```
import React from 'react'

const Scoreboard = ({ scoresArr }) => {

    let id = 0;

    return (
        <div>
            <ul className='pagination'>
             {scoresArr.map((score) => (
                    <li key={id++} className='page-link'>
                        {score}
                    </li>   
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Scoreboard
```

Pins.js

```
import React from 'react'

const Pins = ({ addScore }) => {

    const pinsArr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

    return (
        <div>
            <ul className='pagination'>
                {pinsArr.map((pins) => (
                    <li key={pins} className='page-item'>
                        <a onClick={() => addScore(pins)} className='page-link'>
                            {pins}
                        </a>
                    </li>   
                ))}
            </ul>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Pins
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to avoid forcefully mutating the state. When you do `scoresArr.push()`, you are directly changing an existing state-value. This is against React principles and could lead to visual side-effects to your code, like what your bug is doing.

Instead of mutating state, let's make use of the `setScoresArr` updater that you have. We will give the `scoresArr` a completely new array so that our changes appear as expected.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Scoreboard from "./Scoreboard";
import Pins from "./Pins";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [pinCount, setPinCount] = useState(0);
  const [scoresArr, setScoresArr] = useState([]);

  const addScore = pins => {
    setPinCount(pins);
    setScoresArr([...scoresArr, pins]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      pinCount = {pinCount}
      <Pins addScore={addScore} />
      <Scoreboard scoresArr={scoresArr} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-lake-e0e0n